# QuickBooks Web Connector failing to connect to QB - how to prevent?

Tags: quickbooks

We've successfully integrated QBWC into our application (with around 30 company files), but after a few days of running, many of these company files are failing to be read, giving us the following error:

> Recent changes to your configuration require you (the QuickBooks
>   Administrator) to go into the Integrated Applications preferences and
>   re-authorize your integrated application to log in automatically.

As far as we can tell, nothing has changed within the permissions of the company files to cause this.

We have followed steps to re-authorize the QBWC application and these steps **do fix the issue**, but we'd like to know if there's anything we can do to prevent this from happening in the first place (so we don't have to manually update 20 company file permissions every few days).

Thanks much!

UPDATE: We've noticed a pattern with the failing company files where all the files producing the error have multiple authorized integrations, sometime 2 with the same name. if we reauthorize 1 or all of them, QBWC succeeds. Any idea why some files would show multiple instances of the same authorized integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out another user on the network had changed the Admin password on the affected files, after which QuickBooks requires the re-authentication.